# How do I get French accents to show up properly in a mailto?

Tags: email, mailto, french

I've got a mailto link with body copy. The content is all in French. Unfortunately its showing funny characters instead of the accents that I need.

```
<a title="Prospects" href="mailto:?subject=Pourquoi ne pas investir dans les bons conseils?&amp;body=Madame, Monsieur,%0D%0A%0D%0AÊtes-vous en voie d'atteindre vos objectifs financiers?%0D%0A%0D%0ADes recherches ont révélé que les investisseurs bénéficiant de conseils professionnels s'en tirent beaucoup mieux financièrement. En fait, il a été démontré récemment que ceux faisant appel à un conseiller accumulent presque quatre fois plus d'actifs que les autres.%0D%0A%0D%0AN'hésitez pas à communiquer avec moi pour prendre rendez-vous et en discuter. Veuillez agréer mes plus cordiales salutations.%0D%0A%0D%0ASincerely,%0D%0A%0D%0A&lt;Conseiller&gt;" class="resource_btn"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>Prospection</a>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

I tried encoding the email

https://jsfiddle.net/765rotvu/

https://jsfiddle.net/f8tabmmf/

Answer (score 0):

There's javascript function escape to encode html.

Example:

```
javascript:escape('Êtes-vous là, où étiez-vous ?');
```

Result is

```
%CAtes-vous%20l%E0%2C%20o%F9%20%E9tiez-vous%20%3F
```

Comment: Know that: `The escape() function was deprecated in JavaScript version 1.5. Use encodeURI() or encodeURIComponent() instead.` Result [should be similar](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp).